# Grails 3 hasOne nullability issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm

While migrating an existing app from Grails 2.5 to 3.1, I ran into an odd issue with a bi-directional one-to-one relationship.

Imagine a simple model with a User and `Employee` objects. A `User` represents a generic user account. Not all users are Employees but all Employees are Users. Moreover Employees have references to managers, supervisors, etc (also User instances). User is the owning side of the relationship.

```
class User {
  Employee employee

  static mappedBy = [employee: "user"]
  static hasOne = [employee: Employee]

  static constraints = {
    employee(nullable:true)
  }
}

class Employee {
  User user // represents employee's own account, a bi-directional one-to-one
  User supervisor // represents a supervisor

  static belongsTo = [user: User]

  static constraints = {
    user(unique:true)
    supervisor(nullable:true)
  }
}
```

The trouble after upgrading to Grails 3 is that in the create mode, this results in `supervisor_id` column of employee table being generated as `NOT NULL`, whereas in Grails 2 it was nullable as expected (with only user_id being NOT NULL).

I tested this with Grails 3.1.12 and 3.2.0, getting the same behavior with both. Am I doing anything stupid in my domain class declarations? I've tried multiple mappings to achieve the same behavior as in Grails 2.5 without luck. In some cases I'm even getting a foreign key on both sides of the relationship...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code was working with previous version of Grails, but it is wrong.

When you use `hasMany` and `belongsTo`, it is not necessary to define other property in the child object, and you don't need also to use the `mappedBy` property on the parent, and the same with the parent (property employee at `User`)

Grails doesn't need anything else to know which is the bidirectional property on both classes, and the constraint `user(unique : true)` neither.

So your classes should look like this:

```
class User {

        static hasOne = [employee: Employee]

        static constraints = {
                employee(nullable: true)
        }
}

class Employee {
    User supervisor // represents a supervisor
    static belongsTo = [user: User]

    static constraints = {
        supervisor(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

It could be nice to know how is your DB structure. But in this way all foreign keys are stored in the employee table. But of course you could navigate from both entities. If you have different structure you could map your current database with this model. See [this](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html)

```
employee.user
user.employee
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried your code in Grails 3.2.0 but it still results in a NOT NULL being added to the supervisor_id column of employee table, despite the nullable:true constraint. 

As for the mappedBy on User object, this is a left-over from older code where the one-to-one mapping was optional and the owning side was the other way around (but the foreign key was always on the user side)

Comment: The important thing to note is that Grails itself honors the nullable constraint (even with my original "bad" code) so when you run against an existing or manually created database schema, it works as expected. But it's the hbm2ddl schema that gets generated incorrectly with a NOT NULL applied to those columns, and this breaks our integration tests running against an in-memory H2 database.

Comment: You are welcome. I will try to reproduce it in a few hours, and will make you know.